# serialize state of scriptcs (csharp REPL) session for later re-opening

Tags: c#, .net, mono, read-eval-print-loop, scriptcs

Is it possible to save (serialize) the state of scriptcs session and retrieve (deserialize) it back later on?

This is possible e.g. with dill for python/ipython.

Answer (score 0):

As of Scriptcs v0.15, this is not possible. It's an interesting idea, though!